Is there an example of a unital homomorphism that breaks involution?
Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. It is well-known that characters (nonzero homomorphisms) $h: A\to \mathbb{C}$ preserves the involution $*$. But is this still true for general unital homomorphisms between $C^*$-algebras? Are there well-known counterexamples? Thanks in advance.

Look up Kadison's similarity problem :)

@Justdroppedin Thanks!!! I thought it's only a small question....

You may want to rephrase your question. A homomorphism of $C^*$-algebras preserves the involution by definition. You mean something else. Also, please avoid problem statement questions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards

It's no longer true, and the hint is given in the formulation of Kadison's similarity problem.
Take $A=M_n(\mathbb C)\simeq B(\mathbb C^n)$, consider the (bounded and $\mathbb C$-algebraic) homomorphism (actually an inner isomorphism algebraically) from $A$ to itself:
$$a\mapsto b^{-1}ab$$ where $b\in A$ is a fixed element.
This is a $*$-homomorphism iff $\forall a\in A, (b^{-1}ab)^*=b^{-1}a^*b\Leftrightarrow bb^*a^*=a^*bb^*$, that is $bb^*$ commutes with all $n\times n$ matrices $a$, therefore $bb^*=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb C^*$. Now it's easy to come up with a counter example.
See also Algebraic isomorphism between two C$^\ast$-algebras implies $\ast$-isomorphic.
Related results:

If the homomorphism happens to be an isometry (onto its image),
the answer is yes.
And an injective $*$-homomorphism is automatically an isometry.


Please don't answer no-effort questions. See here for details.

I believe my customized judgement is better than a fixed "rule".
